# How run .NET on a VM from Azure?

Tags: .net, azure

I have a Azure VM Machine 2016 Windows Server.

When i go to "Turn Windows Features on or off", they show that .NET is installed but when i got to cmd and do.

"dotnet --version", they say that don't reconegnize this command like is not installed. What i must do?

[image]

Comment: The screenshot shows `.NET Framework` not .NET Core. You need to install the correct version of .NET Core, or publish a self-contained application (ie one that contains all the .NET Core runtime files it needs)

Answer (score 1):

There are two things.

1. .NET Framework
2. .NET core or more specially cross-platform.

So It will install .NET Framework 4.8 , 3.5 etc which is not cli based or window based framework.

Now if you want .NET core 3.1 or 5.0 or future one , you have to install SDK or runtime based on your needs. You also needs to install IIS bundle if required.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download